# single hook_form for many form ids

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

in my module i am creating a page with many simple forms:

```
foreach ($parameters as $param){
  $output = drupal_get_form('mymodule_param_'.$param['id'].'_form', $product);
}
print $output;
```

i need to find a way to implement a single mymodule_param_form function (and the _validate , _submit  ) that will apply on each $param['id'] in my $params array.
i trust drupal to allow such behavior. just didnt find it yet.
any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You practically posted your own answer: [`hook_forms`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_forms/6)

Comment: but the call to 
drupal_get_form still expects the first argument to be a valid function call back. so my hook_forms implementation get called, i still get an error "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback"

Comment: thanks dude. i figured that my hook_forms should declare the form_id it got.

Comment: Also note that hook_form() is something completely else. That is a hook for a node type form defined by your module. Working with any other form has nothing to do with hook_form() hook_validate() or anything like that.